# Unable to get value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I use flowplayer to display a video. It works in firefox and chrome. But it does not work in iexplorer. The error gives to me is that:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined for document.getElementById(src_row).innerHTML. There is value for "src_row", but there is no value for innerHTML.

The function is attached below. Please help how to make it work using ie. Thanks

```
function copyRows(dest_row, src_row_id){
    var src_row = 'row' + src_row_id.toString(); 
    document.getElementById(dest_row).innerHTML = document.getElementById(src_row).innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: This is an IE bug, there is a work around here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228

Comment: @kidz You think the OP's script is related to a `<select>` element? Especially when the text references "rows"?

Comment: One of your `getElementById` calls is failing to return what you expect. There is not enough code here to diagnose.

Comment: @ianpgall: IE does have a similar issue with table elements and `.innerHTML`. This would be a better link:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239832

Comment: @user1689607 That's all I meant. Instead of googling "IE innerHTML problem" and posting one of the first links (haven't checked what is returned)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to `src_row` in your `getElementById` call, but it appears that you are modifying the `ID` before calling it.

```
var src_row = 'row' + src_row_id.toString(); 
document.getElementById(src_row)
```

assuming a call like this:

```
copyRows( myRow, 'rowID' );
```

`getElementById(src_row)` will look for an element with `ID` of `rowrowID`.

Is that your intent? To append 'row' to the begninning of the ID?

Comment: OP said it works in Firefox and Chrome, so the code implementation is likely correct.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that, but was still suspect.

Comment: Definitely not enough info in the question. I'm guessing OP is trying to use `.innerHTML` with table elements, which doesn't work in older IE.

Comment: @user1689607 Can you use `innerHTML` in table cells at least? Or is it all table elements that IE doesn't like using `innerHTML` with? I guess I'd understand table, thead, tbody, and tr, but not so much td.

Comment: @ianpgall: Yeah, `td` content is safe to set.

Comment: @user1689607 Haha okay, scared me for a minute. I thought it's worked for me before though

Answer (score -1):

```
function copyRows(dest_row, src_row_id){
    var src_row = 'row' + src_row_id.toString(); 
    console.log(src_row);
    document.getElementById(dest_row).innerHTML = document.getElementById(src_row).innerHTML;
}
```

See if that gives you the string you are looking for.